# working with JSONP on iOS

Tags: ios, json, ios5, cross-domain, jsonp

My current `JSONP` research indicate that, one thing which make it different from `JSON` is its ability to fetch data in a cross domain environment.

But from the development point of view, specially native iOS and web technologies like JS HTML. will there be any difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no cross-domain restrictions in native iOS apps. You can communicate anywhere that is exposed.

For web apps running in a native shell like PhoneGap that use AJAX to communicate with a service for JSON data, cross-domain restrictions don't exist either. PhoneGap for example is running on the file:// protocol which doesn't have to adhere to same-domain AJAX restrictions.

For web apps running in Safari that use AJAX to communicate with a service for JSON data, cross-domain restrictions will apply. JSONP could be used in this situation.

Comment: Thanks, and also, the same restriction will apply if you use `UIWebView` with in a native app and try to make AJAX request.